# Powering an rc car motor with arduino

Tags: led

I have a weird problem. When I power an rc car motor through the 5v or the 3.3V arduino's outputs everything goes fine, while powering it through digitalPins does not work.
I'm testing digitalPins with a simple led Blink example. Leds work, the motor does not move. Shouldn't digitalWrite(pinNumber, HIGH) output 5volts? What is the difference between digitalWrite voltage and 5v board output voltage? It seems crazy to me that leds light up without problems but the motor remains motionless...

Comment: Do you know how much current a digital pin can provide? Do you know how much current the motor draws? Please update your question with those details.

Comment: I deserve these answers ;)

Answer (score 4):

Never ever power a motor or anything, that needs that much power, through a digital output pin. The maximum rating is 40mA, though you should not draw more than 20mA continuously from it. Also there is an overall limit of 100mA over all digital pins together. If you are drawing more from the pins, first the voltage will drop immediately, since the pin cannot provide what you ask for. Then you can easily destroy the pins output hardware or the whole Arduino. For an LED you normally use a current limiting resistor, so that it does not draw too much current from the pin.

For anything with more current demands, you need some kind of driver, which will take the big current load of the microcontroller. The easiest driver is a transistor or MOSFET (to switch the motor on and off or to have different speeds). If you want the motor to spin in both directions, you need an H-bridge driver (effectively 4 transistors/MOSFETs).

Note: I'm talking about simple DC motors here. Other types of motors need other types of drivers.

Comment: Good answer. Note that you probably also need a flyback diode to protect the transistor from the inductive motor coils

Comment: It's also not a great idea to drive anything but the smallest motors from the 3.3V or 5V outputs on the Arduino board. Those have very modest current output, and the noisy load of a motor will likely cause the power to everything else to bobble, even if it doesn't exceed the low current limits of those supply lines